# Xamarin Forms with BlinkId OCR Image Result

Tags: xamarin

From the IDocumentFaceRecognizer result, it returns a face image as an imagesource, but I need it as a byte array or stream. How can I get a reference to the original source, so I can save the image locally to my device?

Thanks

Comment: based on the code I don't see an obvious way to do this.  You should probably check the docs and then create a Github issue

Answer (score 0):

We already answer it on the [Github](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-xamarin/issues/17), but I will post it here to keep everyone in the loop:

The original source is platform dependent and does not always exist in form of byte array. You can see how SDK creates ImageSource object on [Android](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-xamarin/blob/master/Binding/Forms/BlinkID.Forms/BlinkID.Forms.Android/Recognizers/Utils.cs) and on [iOS](https://github.com/BlinkID/blinkid-xamarin/blob/master/Binding/Forms/BlinkID.Forms/BlinkID.Forms.iOS/Recognizers/Utils.cs). You can change the source code of these functions to adapt to your needs for the platform you are targeting.

Best regards